# why does the `View` function takes so long to run?

Tags: r, rstudio

I like to use the `View` function in RStudio to see if my data was loaded correctly. 
But, when the data is "big" this function takes a lot of time to run.

This is the timing for a 2MM rows and 9 column data.frame

```
> system.time(View(bd_cadastral))
 user  system elapsed 
3.156   0.004   3.164
```

In RStudio, the function shows only the first 1000 rows, so if I do `View(bd_cadastral[1:1000,]`:

```
> system.time(View(bd_cadastral[1:1000,]))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.068   0.000   0.089
```

Shouldn't this take about the same time?

Comment: Well it takes a little bit of time to make a spreadsheet-like html doc on 2 million rows.  What makes you think that 1000 rows would take the same amount of time as 2 million?

Comment: I can imagine, but why does the function make the spreadsheeto on every row, for showing only the first 1000?

Comment: I really think this question should go to the RStudio development team directly :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look inside the function, you'll see that it doesn't directly take the subset it is going to show. It first tries to coerce the whole thing into a data frame and uses `lapply` and `sapply` on the possibly converted input. And even at the very end, it passes the whole variable to the C program which I assume does the subsetting. All those steps works faster with an initially smaller object.

If you are asking why it was built that way... hell if I know. Possibly in case limitations of the c program change or something.

Side note: Ctrl+Click on a function leads you to its code. For questions like that it can be useful

Comment: by the way when I try to test the individual parts of the program, I noticed I can't use `.External2(C_dataviewer, x, title)` command since it gives an object not found error outside the view function. I tried defining another function but it didn't work. anyone know why?